# For loop does not work appropriate for the function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, port-scanning

Here is a for loop contains a function which specify whether the port is open or closed by using checkPort function.

```
var IPAdress = '192.168'; //Local area network to scan (this is rough)
var Portadd = 80; 
var Newip;
var i=0;
var j=0;
//scan over a range of IP addresses and execute a function each time the port is shown to be open.
for(i=0; i <= 1; i++){
for(j=0; j <= 3; j++){
Newip = IPAdress+'.'+i+'.'+j;

checkPort(Portadd, Newip, function(error, status, host, port) {
// Status should be 'open' since the HTTP server is listening on that port
if(status == "open"){
        console.log("IP" , Newip, "on port" , Portadd, "is open");
    }
else if(status == "closed"){
        console.log("IP" , Newip, "on port" , Portadd, "is closed");
    }
});

console.log(Newip);
}
}
```

and this is the result:

```
192.168.0.0
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.1.0
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
IP 192.168.1.3 on port 80 is closed
IP 192.168.1.3 on port 80 is closed
IP 192.168.1.3 on port 80 is closed
IP 192.168.1.3 on port 80 is closed
IP 192.168.1.3 on port 80 is closed
IP 192.168.1.3 on port 80 is closed
IP 192.168.1.3 on port 80 is closed
IP 192.168.1.3 on port 80 is closed
```

since the NewIp as it is printed out works properly, I expected the result to be for example something like this:

```
IP 192.168.0.0 on port 80 is closed
IP 192.168.0.1 on port 80 is closed
IP 192.168.0.2 on port 80 is closed
IP 192.168.0.3 on port 80 is closed
IP 192.168.1.0 on port 80 is closed
IP 192.168.1.1 on port 80 is closed
IP 192.168.1.2 on port 80 is closed
IP 192.168.1.3 on port 80 is closed
```

Does anybody have an idea that why it shows the IPs like that in the actual result part?

Comment: Is this C#? VB.Net? VBA... what? Or javascript? Have we closed over the Newip badly?

Comment: Sometimes if you add a language tag you get more help.

Comment: good guidance. Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkPort` is using a callback function that is executed later, and by the time it is executed all the IP addresses have been changed in the variable `NewIP`.

So the result is the callback function prints the last value of `NewIP`, because it's referencing that value.

You have two alternatives:

- You can use the parameter `host` that is passed to the callback function instead.
- Define `var NewIP` inside the inner for loop by changing `var Newip = IPAdress+'.'+i+'.'+j;`. This will create a variable that is scoped to the callback function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was really useful. Now I know that what is the problem. I want to search through IPs 192.168.x.y which x is 0-2 for example and y is 0-4. How should I write down var host instead of that? var host = options.host || '192.168.0.1'

Comment: I have adder var NewIP inside the inner loop but the result did not change. Could you please tell me that how should I define var host based on the IP ranges which I have mentioned?

Comment: Can you post an example to jsfiddle.net

Comment: You aren't using `host` and `port` in the callback. Remove those parameters.

Comment: Done. But still the problem exists. :( dont know what to do

Comment: @user3834704 use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
checkPort(Portadd, Newip, function(error, status, host, port) {
    // Status should be 'open' since the HTTP server is listening on that port
    if(status == "open"){
            console.log("IP" , host, "on port" , port, "is open");
    }
    else if(status == "closed"){
            console.log("IP" , host, "on port" , port, "is closed");
    }
});
```

You can't pass "parrent" variable into callback function, expecially You having `host` and `port` input parameter.

Full example for ip adresses in range 192.168.X.Y for X in [0,1,2] and Y in [0,1,2,3,4]:

```
var IPAdress = '192.168'; //Local area network to scan (this is rough)
var Portadd = 80; 
var i=0;
var j=0;

//scan over a range of IP addresses and execute a function each time the port is shown to be open.
for(i=0; i <= 2; i++){
    for(j=0; j <= 4; j++){
        var Newip = IPAdress + '.' + i + '.' + j;

        checkPort(Portadd, Newip, function(error, status, host, port) {
            // Status should be 'open' since the HTTP server is listening on that port
            if(status == "open"){
                console.log("IP" , host, "on port" , port, "is open");
            }else if(status == "closed"){
                console.log("IP" , host, "on port" , port, "is closed");
            }
        });

        console.log(Newip);
    }
}
```

Comment: Draw attention to the difference and explain, if that's all the same and you don't mind...

Comment: I want to search through IPs 192.168.x.y which x is 0-2 for example and y is 0-4. How should I write down var host instead of that? var host = options.host || '192.168.0.1'

Comment: Thank you. In this case what should be written for var host? sorry That I am asking this question since my JS is not very good.

Comment: I have adder var NewIP inside the inner loop but the result did not change. Could you please tell me that how should I define var host based on the IP ranges which I have mentioned?

Comment: variables: `error`, `status`, `host` and `port` are input parameters. The `function(error, status,host,port){ ..... }` means: Let me define anonymous function with 4 input parameters: `error`, `status`, `host` and `port`.